# Get back BulkWriteError from the Mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I want to store `writeErrors` documents into another collection in MongoDB while performing a `bulk.execute()`. I am basically doing a bulk insert/update but want to capture all the errors into another collection in parallel to the bulk operation.

I can see the `BulkWriteError` object is returned in Mongo-Shell, I can also see the `writeErrors` array in the object. But how can I capture it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can see the BulkWriteError object is returned in Mongo-Shell

It is not *returned*. This is a *raised* exception. You need a `try...catch` block to get it back:

```
> bulk = db.w.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
> bulk.insert({_id:1})
> bulk.insert({_id:1})
> try { result = bulk.execute() } catch(e) { err = e }

> err
BulkWriteError({
    "writeErrors" : [
        {
            "index" : 1,
            "code" : 11000,
            "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: test.w.$_id_ dup key: { : 1.0 }",
            "op" : {
                "_id" : 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 1,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
})
```

---

Surprisingly enough, it is rather painful to store the `BulkWriteError` in a collection. One easy way of doing (not necessary an elegant way, though) is to parse the JSON representation of the error to get back the field(s) that interest you.

```
> db.errlog.insert(JSON.parse(err.tojson()).writeErrors)
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//      parse the JSON representation of `BulkWriteError`
```

That way, you get back the array of write errors, that `insert` will happily store in the collection:

```
> db.errlog.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55619737c0c8238aef6e21c5"),
    "index" : 0,
    "code" : 11000,
    "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: test.w.$_id_ dup key: { : 1.0 }",
    "op" : {
        "_id" : 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sylvain, for the valuable answer. 
I am able to persist the writeErrors into my collection. Although, it is now persisting the entire writeErrors elements!
I can see that "index", "code" and "errmsg" has been stored, but "op" which is returned from getOperation() as an array, has not been persisted. Any suggestions on how I can persist writeError.op[] values as well.

Comment: @VivekGupta Persisting the error object was not as easy as I though it was. See my edit, parsing the JSON representation of the error to allow an easy insert in a collection.

Comment: Yes, indeed it was not easy! Really apreciate your help. I did used your reference code to get the desired result I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

In accordance with https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js (line 363):

```
// Bulk errors are basically bulk results with additional error information
BulkWriteResult.apply(this, arguments);
```

So you can use the BulkWriteResult.getWriteErrors() method.

```
try {
    bulk.execute();
    ...
} catch(err) {
    if ("name" in err && err.name == 'BulkWriteError') {
        var wErrors = err.getWriteErrors();
        wErrors.forEach(function(doc){
            db.errlog.insert(doc);
        });
    }
}
```